# SharePoint 2013 REST How to select a look up field and also filter based on look up field?

Tags: rest, sharepoint, odata, sharepoint-2013

I can't select look up field in my SharePoint 2013 List.
also I can't filter base on a Look up field.

for example I have List with Name Test and this list has fields: Title, Company, Province
the Company and Province is look up fields I want to filter based on Province which is a look up field
using REST query it gives error:

my query:

```
https://TestServer/sites/AIB/OBC/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Test')/items?$select=Province/Title&$expand=Province&$filter=Province/Title eq 'ABC'
```

it gives error when I put the URL in My browser for testing it gives the blow error:

```
<m:message xml:lang="en-US">The field or property 'Province' does not exist.</m:message>
```

How to filter based on a look up field in SharePoint 2013 REST ?

Comment: Please take a look at this question in SharePoint Stack:

http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/118633/how-to-select-and-filter-list-items-lookup-column-with-sharepoint-2013-rest-feat/118659#118659

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### How to filter by lookup field value using SharePoint REST

Assume a `Contacts` list that contains a lookup field named `Province`

**Option 1**

When a lookup column is being added into list, its `ID` become accessible automatically via REST. For example, when the field named `Province` is added into List, `Province Id` could be set or get via `ProvinceId` property of List Item.

The following query demonstrate how to filter list items by *lookup field Id* (`Province Id` in our case):

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('<list title>')/items?$filter=LookupField eq <ProvinceId>
```

where `<ProvinceId>` is a province id

**Option 2**

In order to filter by *lookup value*, the query should contain `$expand` query option to retrieve projected fields (like `Province Title`). The following example demonstrates how to filter by *lookup field value* (by `Province Title` in our case):

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Contacts')/items?$select=Province/Title&$expand=Province&$filter=Province/Title eq <ProvinceTitle>
```

where `<ProvinceTitle>` is a `Title` of Province

Answer (score 3):

Use $expand like blow code:

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Test')/items?$select=Province/Title&$expand=Province&$filter=Province/Title eq 'XYZ'
```

Comment: It gives error: The field or property 'Province' does not exist

Comment: This is the technique I used. I did make reference to the wrong table to start with. Be sure you are expanding the LookUp table properly. I had some bad cut/paste from a previous $expand and forgot to update things perfectly. Beyond that, the smallest typo is an issue. I built the URL in the browser and when I got that to work I moved it back to my ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

Mehdi jalal, I found why it was throwing that error. You need to close your ProvinceTitle with Single Quotes and there you have it. like this

Query Syntax:
`/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Contacts')/items?$select=Province/Title,Province/ID&$expand=Province&$filter=Province/Title eq '<ProvinceTitle>'`

Now this is Example Query:
`/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Contacts')/items?$select=Province/Title,Province/ID&$expand=Province&$filter=Province/Title eq 'Detroit Province'`