# Creating a Bot Framework lookup field

Tags: sharepoint, botframework, lookup

I use MS Bot Framework for creating bot for MS Teams.

I need to figure out how to implement a lookup field so that it fetches information through an odata feed from a sharepoint list

Comment: Hi @danil-kalinin. Can you expand a little bit here please? Are you wanting chat users to actually be able to select an option that comes from a SharePoint list/field? You can use [middleware](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-middleware?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) to make calls to SharePoint using odata. You'll need to have your own logic on what the users will be supplying (remember; users will only be able to supply text/voice/img) that will get used by the middleware, as well as how you want to present data to users (text/hero card/suggested actions)

Comment: @dana-v The fact is that there are more than 4000 items in the SharePoint list

Comment: I still need a little bit more clarification. Are you stating that there are 4000 unique values that the lookup column can surface? Are you wanting to present those 4000 values as choices to the user to select one?

Comment: To put it a better way; do you need help: retrieving the values from the lookup field, or how to present those values to a user in in the botframework?

Comment: @dana-v, that's what I need...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can give little help on the SharePoint side. If possible, you might consider using a filter to limit the amount of values returned:

- http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/Applying-Filters-to-Lookup-Fields-with-the-SP2013-REST-API
- [SharePoint 2013 REST How to select a look up field and also filter based on look up field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26479319/sharepoint-2013-rest-how-to-select-a-look-up-field-and-also-filter-based-on-look)
- https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/118633/how-to-select-and-filter-list-items-lookup-column-with-sharepoint-2013-rest-feat/118659#118659

Depending on the size that a filtered set returns (if you do so), you might also/instead want to use paging:

- https://platinumdogs.me/2013/05/14/client-and-server-driven-paging-with-the-sharepoint-rest-api/
- https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/45719/paging-using-rest-odata-with-sp-2013

On the botframework side; how do you want to present to the users? Do you want to supply a limited amount of data (say 20 values, for example), then have them give feedback on whether or not that contains the data they need? If so, you can split the data returned from SharePoint into chunks and use a waterfall dialog to accomplish that. Optionally, if you paged data from SharePoint you could; get one page, query user, get another page, query user again, etc. until whatever goal was achieved.

Unfortunately, you're not giving enough information on the actual goal or what you are expecting this functionality to look like in the end.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. I need a drop-down menu that gives the result depending on what the user entered in the text box

Comment: Sounds good. Remember that different channels render things differently. I'm not sure that you could get a drop-down in Teams (you might), but I would investigate adaptive cards and a choice set using "style": "compact"  and "isMultiSelect": false. 
https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Input.ChoiceSet.html